# Avoid StreamBuilder refreshing running SetState in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a page which displays 2 elements, both of them are different `StreamBuilder` but the second one depends on the first one.
To make it more clear I display this:

```
Firebase documents (list)
Firebase user
```

If we sign out both `StreamBuilder` disappear. That's fine, but my problem comes when I need to select a document from the list:

```
return ListTile(
leading: FlutterLogo(size: 40.0),
title: Text(set["title"]),
selected: _selected[index],
trailing: Badge(
   badgeColor: Colors.grey,
   shape: BadgeShape.circle,
   toAnimate: true,
onTap: () => setState(() => _selected[index] = !_selected[index]),
);
```

Everytime I do the `SetState()` I refresh the first `StreamBuilder` (not sure why) and with this the second one.

This is the list widget:

```
Widget _mySetsLists(BuildContext context) {
    List<bool> _selected = List.generate(20, (i) => false);

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(user.uid)
                .collection('sets')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return new ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot set = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: FlutterLogo(size: 40.0),
                      title: Text(set["title"]),
                      selected: _selected[index],
                      onTap: () => setState(() => _selected[index] = !_selected[index]),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Text("loadin");
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the user profile:

```
class UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
        [
          _mySetsLists(context),
          Divider(),
          StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
                if (user == null) {
                  return Text('not logged in');
                }
                return ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      user.photoUrl,
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(user.displayName),
                  subtitle: Text(user.email),
                  trailing: new IconButton(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                      highlightColor: Colors.pink,
                      onPressed: () {
                        authService.signOut();
                      }),
                );
              } else {
                return Text("loading profile"); // <---- THIS IS WHAT I SEE
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're asking - can you elaborate more & provide code snippets of the `StreamBuilder`s?

Comment: the problem is when I update the `SetState()` on my second `StreamBuilder`. As commented it refreshes the first one (it shows `loading...`) making my value select value disappear. I wish I could elaborate more but I'm not sure what the problem here is. Code is basically that

Comment: I don't see the `StreamBuilder`s so it's hard to try and see what went wrong. There could be plenty of issues, such as both `StreamBuilder`s being inside your `StatefulWidget` that you're rebuilding, or anything else. You showed the ListTile with a button that changes the state, but the rest of your code is a complete black box, so I can't really point you in any direction :/

Comment: I update the question. Hope it doesn't seem too much.
I realised about something. On list I have `snapshot.hasData`. On the widget which is showing the loading text what I have is `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active`. Having also the first one I don't see any issue showing any message but the selection still not working (basically because the list renders every time I click on one of its elements)

Comment: Even when I move from that page to the next go that `StreamBuilder` gets trigger again (and twice)

Comment: Just in case you need to check the whole page code: https://codeshare.io/5gWQpV

Comment: Okay, so the issue here is that both `StreamBuilder`s are inside the same build function of some `StatefulWidget`. That means whenever you call `setState`, your `build` gets called, which will then re-create the two `StreamBuilder`s. If you don't want that to happen, you want to push the responsibility of managing the `_selected` list as far down the widget tree as you can.

Comment: So you mean not inside the same widget? I need to get the list base on the profile uid

Comment: even when I open the keyboard to start typing on a `textField` on a different page I also see that `-loading-` message. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

If you pretend to use setstat a lot using the stream you can download the data locally. So every reload will not download data again, but just show the local data.

First step: declare the variable that will store data locally.

```
QuerySnapshot? querySnapshotGlobal;
```

Then where you read the streamData, first check if the local data you just declared is empty:

```
//check if its empty
if(querySnapshotGlobal==null)
              //as its empty, we will download it from firestore
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _queryAlunos.snapshots(),
              builder: (context, stream){

                if (stream.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }

                else if (stream.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text(stream.error.toString()));
                }


                else if(stream.connectionState == ConnectionState.active){

                  //QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot = stream.data;
                  //instead of save data here, lets save it in the variable we declared
                  querySnapshotGlobal = stream.data;

                  return querySnapshotGlobal!.size == 0
                      ? Center(child: Text('Sem alunos nesta turma'),)
                      : Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: querySnapshotGlobal!.size,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){

                        Map<String, dynamic> map = querySnapshotGlobal!.docs[index].data();

                        //let it build
                        return _listDeAlunoswid(map, querySnapshotGlobal!.docs[index].id);

                      },
                    ),
                  );

                }

                return CircularProgressIndicator();

              },
            )
            else
              //now, if you call setstate, as the variable with the data is not empty, will call it from here e instead of download it again from firestore, will load the local data
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: querySnapshotGlobal!.size,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){

                    Map<String, dynamic> map = querySnapshotGlobal!.docs[index].data();

                    return _listDeAlunoswid(map, querySnapshotGlobal!.docs[index].id);

                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Hope it helps you save some money!

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I also went through the same difficulty, but this is the trick i used

```
var itemsData = List<dynamic>();
  var _documents = List<DocumentSnapshot>();
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
getData();


  }
getData(){
Firestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .document(currentUser.uid)
      .collection('set')
      .getDocuments()
      .then((value) {
    value.documents.forEach((result) {

      setState(() {
        _documents.add(result);
        itemsData.add(result.data);
      });


    });
  });
}
```

replace your listview builder will be like this

```
ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: _documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return ListTile(
title:Text(itemsData[index]['name'])
)


})
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: But does it also look for changes in the firestore database?